# How to create Slideshow/Slider with multiple items visible on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to create a similar Slideshow/Slider to this one: https://www.earn-a-living.com/en/episodes/

Here's what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/Santos1600/yet42srh/

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Freud Got Lynched</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@200;300;400;500;523;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="site.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <section class="episodios">
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="assets/fundo.png" width="523" height="294">
            <div class="tituloep">Título do Episódio1</div>
            <div class="descricaoep">Pequena descrição do episódio a ocupar, no máximo dos maximos, duas linhas.</div>
          </div>

          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="assets/fundo.png" width="523" height="294">
            <div class="tituloep">Título do Episódio2</div>
            <div class="descricaoep">Pequena descrição do episódio a ocupar, no máximo dos maximos, duas linhas.</div>
          </div>

          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="assets/fundo.png" width="523" height="294">
            <div class="tituloep">Título do Episódio3</div>
            <div class="descricaoep">Pequena descrição do episódio a ocupar, no máximo dos maximos, duas linhas.</div>
          </div>

          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="assets/fundo.png" width="523" height="294">
            <div class="tituloep">Título do Episódio4</div>
            <div class="descricaoep">Pequena descrição do episódio a ocupar, no máximo dos maximos, duas linhas.</div>
          </div>

          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="assets/fundo.png" width="523" height="294">
            <div class="tituloep">Título do Episódio5</div>
            <div class="descricaoep">Pequena descrição do episódio a ocupar, no máximo dos maximos, duas linhas.</div>
          </div>

          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="assets/fundo.png" width="523" height="294">
            <div class="tituloep">Título do Episódio5</div>
            <div class="descricaoep">Pequena descrição do episódio a ocupar, no máximo dos maximos, duas linhas.</div>
          </div>
</div>
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.episodios {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: black;
}

.slideshow-container {
 max-width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.mySlides {
 width: 523px;
 margin: auto;
 display: none;
 height: 500px;
}


.tituloep {
 color: #f2f2f2;
 font-size: 20pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: 'Manrope';
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
 width: 100%; }

.descricaoep {
 color: #f2f2f2;
 font-size: 13pt;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 font-family: 'Manrope';
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
 width: 100%; }

 /* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 width: auto;
 margin-top: -22px;
 padding: 16px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 30px;
 transition: 0.6s ease;
 border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
 user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
 right: 0;
 border-radius: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
 background-color: gray;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
 -webkit-animation-name: fade;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s;
 animation-name: fade;
 animation-duration: 2.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
 from {opacity: .2}
 to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
 from {opacity: .2}
 to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Javascript

```
//Slideshow
  var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1;}    
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  }
```

Alongside the fact that I have no idea how to make the slideshow/slider have multiple itens visible on screen at any giving moment, the code I currently also doesn't seem to be working properly, since when I load the page, the first item stays hidden, and only appear after clicking the previous and next buttons.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's so much code lines.... HTML, CSS, Javascript. You say "It's break", we look at this and... What? Can someone debug code in own head? Man, put it in jsfiddle (or something like it), then people can _see_ the problem.

Comment: Before i add it to the main post, can you check it out through this link: https://jsfiddle.net/Santos1600/yet42srh/? Sorry, never posted anything on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do it with fade animation.

```
.slideshow-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.mySlides {
    /* display: none; */

    flex: 1 1 calc(100% / 3);
}
```

this is not the right way. workaround to the problem.

I recommend using one of the slider packages.

- https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
- https://swiperjs.com/

Comment: Thank you. Will try making it work with the slick package.